# Azure Module for ACR

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-container-registry, azure-runbook

Im trying to deploy a Runbook that executes some cmdlets from ACR. For example: az acr repository list

Which module do I have to import?

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm fairly certain az cli is not available in Azure Automation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure runbook does not support the type of Azure CLI currently.

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-types

The customer feedback and the response of the Automation Team.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/246290-automation/suggestions/32547325-az-cli-support-in-runbooks

[image]